# How to create and populate multiple tables from multidimensional array using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create and populate multiple tables from a multidimensional array. My array is a multidimensional array that looks like below:

```
{
    "John Snow": [
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "id": "28",
            "clock_in": "2019-06-03 14:32:14",
            "clock_out": "2019-06-04 14:32:14",
            "time": "24.00",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Snow"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "id": "29",
            "clock_in": "2019-06-04 20:47:18",
            "clock_out": "2019-06-05 18:47:18",
            "time": "22.00",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Snow"
        }
    ],
    "Frank Thomas": [
        {
            "user_id": "6",
            "id": "30",
            "clock_in": "2019-06-03 06:32:04",
            "clock_out": "2019-06-05 14:05:04",
            "time": "55.55",
            "first_name": "Frank",
            "last_name": "Thomas"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure how to loop through this with javascript, I'm guessing I will need to nest a for loop but not sure how to structure it.

I was able to loop through and populate a single table just fine when my array structure was a single array with no keys using the below code:

```
<div id="tables"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


function search_data(){
            var fromDate = $('#from_date').val();
            var toDate = $('#to_date').val();
            var userId = $('#employee_option').val();


            $.ajax({

                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>clock/search_data",
                method:"post",
                dataType:"JSON",
                data:{fromDate:fromDate, toDate:toDate, userId:userId},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data)

                    var html = '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive" id="myTable"><thead><tr><th>Employee</th><th>Time In</th><th>Time Out</th><th>Total Time</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

                     for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++){
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data-column_name="id" >'+data[count].first_name+" "+data[count].last_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td><input type="text" class="dateedit" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data-column_name="clock_in" value="'+data[count].clock_in+'"></td>';
                        html += '<td><input type="text" class="dateedit" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data-column_name="clock_out" value="'+data[count].clock_out+'"></td>';
                        html += '<td class="table_data" data-row_id="'+data[count].id+'" data-column_name="time">'+data[count].time+'</td>';
                        html += '<td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="'+data[count].id+'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td></tr>';

                     }   

                     $('#tables').html(html);
                     $('.dateedit').each(function(){ 
                        $(this).datetimepicker({
                            format: "YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss",
                            sideBySide: true

                        });

                     });


                 }
                });

        }
        </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, hopefully this makes sense.
Here is a picture of what I have with a basic array:
 [image: Need]

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
[image: Want]

Comment: You might be able to do this with CSS Grid. It might make it easier to lay things out as you like.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? A nested loop is probably the way to go. Or you could do a loop which calls a function & have that function lay out a clock record for a given person. And what should the tables look like? You say multiple tables, but there's no example of how that should be set up

Comment: Updated post to show what I have and what I am trying to accomplish, Table structure is in picture.

Comment: Okay... so you want a different table for each employee? So "John Snow" would have his own table & "Frank Thomas" would have his own table as well? Rather than having all the employees in one table

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop over the employees and pass them to another function to print out each employee... because I find nested loops hard to understand. easier to maintain & modify separate functions, IMO.

Note: I am a PHP dev who does minimal javascript, so don't expect my code to be up to snuff. I think this does what you want.

```js
let employees = {
    "John Snow": [
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "id": "28",
            "clock_in": "2019-06-03 14:32:14",
            "clock_out": "2019-06-04 14:32:14",
            "time": "24.00",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Snow"
        },
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "id": "29",
            "clock_in": "2019-06-04 20:47:18",
            "clock_out": "2019-06-05 18:47:18",
            "time": "22.00",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Snow"
        }
    ],
    "Frank Thomas": [
        {
            "user_id": "6",
            "id": "30",
            "clock_in": "2019-06-03 06:32:04",
            "clock_out": "2019-06-05 14:05:04",
            "time": "55.55",
            "first_name": "Frank",
            "last_name": "Thomas"
        }
    ]
};

function get_employee_table(employeeName, employees){
 let str = "<table><tr><td>Employee Name</td><td>Clock In</td><td>Clock Out</td></tr>";
    for (let index in employees[employeeName]){
        let clock = employees[employeeName][index];
        str +="<tr><td>"+(clock['first_name']+" "+clock['last_name'])+"</td>"
            + "<td>"+clock['clock_in']+"</td>"
            + "<td>"+clock['clock_out']+"</td>"
            + "</tr>";
    }
    str +="</table>";
    return str;
}

for (let employee in employees){

    document.getElementById("employee_table_demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("employee_table_demo").innerHTML + 
get_employee_table(employee,employees);
}
```

```html
<div id="employee_table_demo"></div>
```

Now... here's where I share my opinion. I think you probably could have done this on your own. I had a hard time figuring out how to correctly loop over the objects, since the `forin` gave me the key, rather than the value. But the actual operation wasn't very complex. I realize we're all at different stages in our skill set, and if you're newer this could have seemed very perplexing. It seems like the kind of problem, though, that just required more elbow grease and maybe pushing through some frustration. T'was a nice learning experience for me though. And a good way to avoid working on my own projects lol.

Comment: And `get_employee_table` should probably be called like `get_employee_table(employeeName,employeeList[employeeName])` such that the data gets passed in... rather than the list. Then the function definition would be `function get_employee_table(employeeName,employeeClocksList)`. This would require some changes to the function.

Comment: Perfect I can work with this, appreciate it. Ya I am pretty new at coding, don't do this for a living or anything just learning from youtube videos. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. And that totally makes sense. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for..in` loop to loop through the object and `forEach` through the array.

```
for(let row in data) {
  data[row].forEach(cell => {

  ...

  }
}
```